# how fully remove Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Please tell me how to fully remove Visual Studio with all components and also remove registry(Any batch file or any Command which runs from Command prompt)

Answer (score 1):

- Go to *Programs and Features* (in Control Panel)
- click on 'Microsoft Visual Studio *{your distribution e.g. Pro/Ent etc}* 20XX'
- click on *Change*
- click *Uninstall*

Do the same for all other existing Microsoft Visual Studio components in that list.

**EDIT:**
based on your comment below, I'd suggest you to use [Windows 7 Manager](http://download.cnet.com/windows/yamicsoft/3260-20_4-115630-1.html) or [Windows 10 Manager](http://download.cnet.com/windows/yamicsoft/3260-20_4-115630-1.html) based on your OS, its quite handy and fast, it even cleans registry as well. I've personally had good experience with it.

Comment: but take to much time i am from Software Compliance Team and that Uninstallation process take too much time. and i have big count of machines

Comment: and please update your question to clearly state this problem and context of yours so that people can clearly see that its not a question of a simple un-installation